# Under what conditions is an ELResolver's setValue method called?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, el

As far as I know, there is no assignment operator in the EL spec and any attempts to use one results in a ParseException. So then what's the point of having the setValue method? I've implemented it for a custom resolver I'm working on, but I have no clue how to test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called by among others [`ValueExpression#setValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ValueExpression.html#setValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object%29) which is in turn used by among others JSF components implementing [`EditableValueHolder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html) interface, such as [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) which has a [`setValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#setValue%28java.lang.Object%29) method for that.

This JSF example,

```html
<h:inputText value="#{bean.property}" />
```

Does deep under the covers basically a (context/conversion/validation/etc omitted for brevity)

```
bean.setProperty(request.getParameter(component.getClientId(facesContext)))
```

That `setProperty()` call is ultimately done by [`ELResolver#setValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html#setValue%28javax.el.ELContext,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).

If you aren't using JSF anywhere in your webapp, then you don't necessarily need to worry about it. If you want to test it on JSF anyway, then use the Hello World example in [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).